Confused and need suggestions for a clean install of Ubuntu Mate 24.04.1
Last clean install was 20.04.4,  built a new system with an MSI Pro B550M-VC WIFI, Ryzen 7 5700G, 64G of DDR4 DRAM (primarily to avoid memory paging).  It has a variety of HDD and SDD drives.  SSD for fast stable use, HDD for things that may need bulk space or more writes (always concerned about the endurance of SSDs but I'm sure I'll come around eventually  :-)
Also trying out a new thing by using a Ventoy flash drive for installations.  I've downloaded and setup a new flash drive with the current Ventoy and loaded it with Ubuntu 24.04.1 and Ubuntu Mate 24.04.1.  As I downloaded the ISO files and moved them around from Download folder to storage spaces and then to the Ventoy drive I did gtkhash checks to make sure they were copied correctly so I'm certain the ISOs are correct on the Ventoy drive.  Also loaded on the Ventoy is a copy of mt86-plus since this is a new system and a new Ventoy.  (figuring that if the system can load, execute and pass a memory test from Ventoy then bot the Ventoy and the system must be in a basic working state.)
Now, here's where I'm having trouble.  I really want to carry on with Ubuntu Mate since I'm used to it and have been using it for quite some time but I cannot get a completed install of Ubuntu Mate 24.04.1 onto the system.  The installer has lots of interruptions, stopping and dropping out back to the desktop and when it does manage to get into an actual install it stop with a general message saying that there was some system error but no explicit details and the suggestion that the details can be found after running another command.  I've tried that but gotten nothing that looks like a log.  I did try making up a log from two message streams but they don't tell me very much.  nothing of a plain hey, your hard drive failed or there was a memory fault.  so I'm a bit stuck with one further detail.
This message is being entered after doing a fresh clean install of plain Ubuntu 24.04.1 on the same hardware.  it, as the sometimes seen banner says, "just worked".
So same hardware, two software systems, downloaded the same day, with all the chksums correct as they were moved from one media to the next and where one just works and the other not.  if someone would like to see the rather long "log" file I assembled I just need to know where to upload it.
Moving forward.  I do have a working Ubuntu system but not the Ubuntu Mate I was working toward.  I haven't tried it yet but I imagine I could install the Mate Desktop onto the Ubuntu I have but what are the major difference between the two options and how well do they get along if one does any amount of switching between the normal Ubuntu deasktop and the Mate desktop?

Since you have a successful install, you seem to have demonstrated that your LiveUSB (Ventoy) and one set of hardware both work properly. How to troubleshoot your other hardware seems like a broad question better suited to a conversational venue like UbuntuForums.org.

This is a Question and Answer site and not a forum (https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the address of Ubuntu Forums), where a problem on a Q&A site should a well-defined problem (the question) where people can write how they'd solve it (ie. answers). You're seeking opinions which are off-topic here (differences???) and are better suited to Forums, not Q&A sites like this.  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask  (ie. I see no clearly defined problem to solve)

FYI:  I'm a lover of multi-desktop installs; on my box I select which DE(sktop) I'll use for the session at login, today I'm using a Lubuntu session (ie. LXQt desktop), but I could have selected Ubuntu (GNOME), Xubuntu (Xfce) or Ubuntu-MATE (MATE) instead as they're installed... On prior releases one difference between Ubuntu-MATE & Ubuntu Desktop was different installers being used; but with 24.04 they both use the same ubuntu-desktop-installer so installer should be the same (different kernel stacks are installed; but both for now are 6.8 anyway so difference is still in the future)...

If you have a system installed; you can change desktop as the difference really is just different packages installed; with the default set by the ISO used at install, as all Ubuntu flavors and Ubuntu itself are built by the same infrastructure; with seed files just controlling what is put on the ISO; ie. Ubuntu-MATE gets different packages to Ubuntu Desktop; changes you can alter yourself post-install.. Ubuntu MATE 24.04 uses the ubuntu-desktop-installer which is the same installer as used by Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS....  Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS however uses the subiquity installer

Sorry if this wasn't clear. There is only one hardware system and while I can install plain Ubuntu 24.04.1 on it, it fails when I try to install Ubuntu Mate 24.04.1.  Along with the Firefox and Thunderbird snaps, this has been a very troubled hardware and software upgrade.

A multi desktop install (like what I'm using now) in a single install on which multiple desktops are installed; I select which I'll use when I login... My system is actually dual boot; but the dual boot is LTS (24.04) and is likewise a multi-desktop install meaning it has the same options as my current oracular.   You don't specify what Ubuntu 24.04.1 you installed (only giving release, not product (Server? Desktop?)) so may have been using the same installer OR different (if you installed Server) to Ubuntu-MATE; see prior comment.

Wanting to get an Ubuntu Mate 24.04.1 installed so working with that and the comparison and the one that did get installed is just plain Ubuntu Desktop  ( i missed that word before because there are only two version that are relevant to me.  Ubuntu mate and what it was derived from Ubuntu "Desktop" but I always called Ubuntu Desktop just Ubuntu.)  anyway, I think I'm going to just install the Mate Desktop onto this working Ubuntu Desktop, fuddle my way through the Firefox and Thunderbird changes and leave it at that.  Too many sleepless nights lately.

Okay, i'm an idiot.  Runnning out of reasonable options for why one version of a ddistribution will install and not another i went very primitive and checked for a BIOS update.  This motherboard was bought earlier this year but there was a BIOS upgrade available so I applied it.  Voila, the Ventoy install of Ubuntu Mate 24.04.1 ran without a hitch.  Now my big problem is figuring out how  to migrate the profiles from the old .deb versions of Firefox and Ubuntu to the Snap version.     Sorry to trouble you all with this but I was losing my mind over what should have been a much simpler problem.

@KenPoole Please post the preceding comment as an answer to your own question. You can click the big check symbol beside your question to mark it as accepted 24 hours or more after when you asked your question.

gonna make some rude comments ...
